# Creating a Single Page Application with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to create a SPA with the React/Redux/Express stack. My server currently looks like this:

```
import express from 'express'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
import path from 'path'

dotenv.config()

const app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../client/static/public/'))
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 
  '../client/static/public/index.html'))
})
app.listen(process.env.PORT)
```

And in my html, I have a script tag with src="path to webpack bundle file". The src returns the html document and not the content of the bundled file. I know this is because of my catch-all route in my server. My question is how do I set the routes up so that the catch-all does not interfere with other routes? Thank you in advanced!

EDIT:

Here is my full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Backers Online</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="../build/app.bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems you're using `express` middleware in the right order. What does your HTML `src=` look like?

Comment: src="../build/app.bundle.js" @RaphaMex

Comment: There you are. Put your full HTML and I fix it in an answer

Comment: Try my answer. What happened is that your server was looking into `../client/static/public/`. Also you cannot use `..` in HTML for obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `app.use(express.static(...))` is to serve files from a given directory. **For security reasons, it does not serve files out of that directory (like `../build/app.bundle.js`)**. So you should add it as many times as you have directories to serve:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../client/static/public/'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../client/static/build/'));
```

Then on the client side you just request files, HTML being agnostic of which directories hold them:

```
<script src="app.bundle.js"></script>
```

> **EDIT:** You had a typo in the directory paths you serve. Add a `/` like this: `__dirname + '/..'`

As I said in comments, if you display `__dirname` you see it immediately.

Comment: It still is giving me the same error where the src is loading the html file.

Comment: Mmmm... is `../build/` relative to `../client/static/public/` by chance?

Comment: Yes, it is '../client/static/build/'. I changed your answer to correspond with my paths and it didn't work.

Comment: Check your `__dirname`. It should work already. I'm blind there :)

Comment: Try to remove the ending `/`, like: `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../client/static/build'));`